# Is it possible to inject the current firewall's user provider service into a custom service?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony-security

I'm facing a good challenge in one of my projects.

I need to inject the User Provider defined for a firewall in a service of a third party bundle that I'm developing. **I cannot define it explicitly in my service**, because I want to achieve that, when the service is called from a different firewall or the user changes the provider in `security.yaml`, my service adapts to use the right provider.

What I've been able to accomplish is to get just the name of the provider by injecting the `RequestStack` and the `FirewallMap` and getting the `FirewallConfig` using the current request, but nothing more, just the name.

I wonder if there's a way of doing this. There's nothing in the docs with regards to this. But I'm sure there must be a way, since the authentication listeners in Security Bundle do the same.

I'm reading your clever responses! :)

Comment: What release are you using? 4.0?

Comment: Yeap. I'm using 4.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into the `FirewallConfig` class? It's not documented very well, but it exists, and can be accessed via `$firewallMap->GetFirewallConfig($request)`. Every information about the firewall is stored in this object, as well as the provider (`$firewallConfig->getProvider()`).

If you have been able to inject the `FirewallMap` config, I think you can also pass the current `Request` object as a parameter to obtain the `FirewallConfig`:

```
public class YourService()
{
    ...
    public function YourMethod(Request $request)
    {
        // Your FirewallMap injection
        ...

        $firewallConfig = $firewallMap->getFirewallConfig($request);

        // Proceed with $firewallConfig information
    }
}
```

More on the `FirewallConfig` class [here](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Security/FirewallConfig.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help Leon. I'm sorry that I wasn't clear enough and I'm wasting your time. 

This is what I meant that I was able to just get the name of the provider just injecting the `RequestStack` and the `FirewallMap`. In firewall map I call `$map->getFirewallConfig($request)->getProvider()`. But that only returns the name of the provider that has been configured. Maybe there's another service to resolve the provider name, but I can't find anything. Kinda trapped here.

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly you need from the user provider?

Comment: To load a user by the username.